# How to remove +91 from Indian phone numbers in Ameyo

Tags: phone-call

In an inbound contact center for customer service, the phone numbers in the callerid are prefixed with 0 or sometimes with 91. A few inhouse CRMs require very precise phone number without these prefixes. For the CRM popup to work well, it is required that Ameyo removes such prefix, if present. How can it be done

Answer (score -1):

Enable Call Context Inbound Srcphone Script from configuration and paste the following script.
​

```
if(null !=srcphone && srcphone.length>10 && srcphone.charAt(0) =='9' && srcphone.charAt(1) =='1'){
var srcphoneWithout91 = srcphone.substring(2,srcphone.length);
srcphone=srcphoneWithout91;
}
else if(null !=srcphone && srcphone.length>10 && srcphone.charAt(0) =='0'){
var srcphoneWithout91 = srcphone.substring(1,srcphone.length);
srcphone=srcphoneWithout91;
}
else {
srcphone;
}
```